# get characters from string by index in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I may just be tired and not thinking properly anymore, but why is "13" only printed once here? (intelliJ tells me that "`i == 11 | i == 13`" is always true but I don't see how that makes sense)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            String line = clientReader.readLine();
            int length = line.length();
            if (i == 0 || i == 5 || i == 6) {
                line = line.substring(7, length - 6);
            } else if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 9 || i == 10 || i == 12) {
                line = line.substring(8, length - 7);
            } else if (i == 7) {
                line = line.substring(9, length - 8);
            } else if (i == 11 || i == 13) {
                line = line.substring(10, length - 9);

            }
            data[i] = line;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

p.s. The line.substring does not give an error, if I add System.out.println(line) at the end of the last else if it prints the correct thing.

Comment: use || instead of | in if conditions

Comment: Oh yeah will do, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The last `else if` is always true because your loop control variable runs from `0` until `13` and the only two numbers you haven't checked before the last `else if` is `11` and `13` therefore if none of the above conditions are true then `i` will either be `11` or `13` hence why IntelliJ is smart enough to know it's always true and hence control will always be bound inside the last `else if` block when the above conditions are not met.

If you increase the loop condition to something like `i < 15` or above then IntelliJ wouldn't state `else if (i == 11 || i == 13)` is always true as `i` could be `14`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's not a problem though, right? This doesn't result in "13" only being printed once, does it?

Comment: my answer so far explains the part of your post --> _"intelliJ tells me that "i == 11 | i == 13" is always true but I don't see how that makes sense"_  and not the --> _"but why is "13" only printed once here?"_. that aside, how many times do you expect it to print 13 and why?

Comment: I was just making sure I wasn't missing anything in your explanation. Thanks for the explanation, it was helpful :). As to the printing issue, I made a dumb mistake; the array data was [13] instead of [14]. I was printing i to debug. I'll delete this post soon, its useles.